# easyimage : set re-sized image background to transparent

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, alpha-transparency

im using easyImage moudel built on top of ImageMagick i'm trying to resize image and set the background to transparent but it always white , there is no good documentation for easyImage moudel here is my code

```
            easyimg.resize({

            src : "assets/pic.png",

            dst : assets/dir/pic.png,

            width : 500,

            background : "transparent",

        }).then(function(){


        });
```

the result image format is png but the background is white 
i tried to set background to null , 0 and "transparent" nothing work 
as i said there is no valid doc , is there any way to do it or any alternative  moudel to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyImage does not support transparency. It passes the background color to ImageMagick via the `-background` flag, which does not do transparency. To use transparency in ImageMagick you need to use the `-transparent` flag, which EasyImage does not include in its options.